Excel LEN formula returning incorrect value for a date field
In Excel:
The field length to be calculated has this value in cell C2: 01/09/2017 00:02:01
The formula used =LEN(C2)
The result returned is 15
The correct number of characters is 19
Format of cell C2 is a custom value: "yyyy"-"mm"-"dd" "hh":"mm":"ss"
When I use this in Google Sheets, the exact same steps, I get the correct value "19".
Please advise what I can correct in Excel, thank you!

Remember that dates in Excel are just sequential numbers formatted to display as dates, not real dates. If the date has a time, the time is the decimal part of the number.
For example, the underlying number for your date/time is 42744.001400463, the reason why the result of len is 15. The number 42777 represents the date, and 001400463 represents the time on that day.
Excel's first possible date/time is the number 1, representing the 1/1/1900  12:00:00 AM. It goes all the way to 12/31/9999  11:59:59 PM.

Yes, you can do =LEN(TEXT(C2,"YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss")).
However, you do not even need the formula!
The formula will return 19 for every possible date/time in Excel, since your format has 19 digits as text, doesn't matter the date/time you insert.
